# Python: Import Tweet unicode data to pandas data frame object

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am attempting to import a file that has the structure below (dump of tweets, with unicode strings).  The goal is to convert this to a DataFrame using the pandas module.  I assume the first step is to load to a json object and then convert to a DataFrame (per p. 166 of McKinney's Python for Data Analysis book) but am unsure and could use some pointers to manage this.

```
import sys, tailer
tweet_sample = tailer.head(open(r'<MyFilePath>\usTweets0.json'), 3)
tweet_sample # returns
['{u\'contributors\': None, u\'truncated\': False, u\'text\': u\'@KREAYSHAWN is...
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in your sample python output, it's not a proper python object atm.

Comment: @AndyHayden Thanks for looking this over and yes, I'm still having a tough time converting this 'str' object into something usable.  Attempted:  `file1 = tweet_sample.encode('utf-8')
file2 = json.dumps(file1,encoding='utf-8', separators=(',', ': '))
print file2`
"{u'contributors': none, u'truncated': false, u'text':... object is still a string and json.load doesn't facilitate a workable solution.

Comment: Hmmm, if it has u'' in the text file you might be better off with `ast.literal_eval`. Perhaps you could link to the actual json? (If it's a string use `json.loads` (!).)

Comment: @AndyHayden Hugely helpful, been working at this and checked in again and that piece of code did it.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the DataFrame constructor...

```
In [6]: tweet_sample = [{'contributers': None, 'truncated': False, 'text': 'foo'}, {'contributers': None, 'truncated': True, 'text': 'bar'}]

In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(tweet_sample)

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
  contributers text truncated
0         None  foo     False
1         None  bar      True
```

If you have the file as a JSON you can open it using [`json.load`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/python-parsing-file-json):

```
import json
with open('<MyFilePath>\usTweets0.json', 'r') as f:
    tweet_sample = json.load(f)
```

*There will be a `from_json` coming [soon](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3583) to pandas...*